# Equivalence of the ellipsoid

Tags: linear-algebra

I just came across this exercise in  Boyd & Vandenberghe.

> Consider an Ellipsoid defined as
> $$
> \mathcal E = \{x \mid (x - x_c)^\top P^{-1} (x - x_c) \leq 1\}
> = \{x_c + Au \mid \|u\|_2 \leq 1\},
> $$
> with $P$ positive definite and $AA^\top = P$.
>
> Show that both definitions are equivalent.

[(image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DbfR.png)

I'm not pretty sure what's the most basic manner I could have used for solving this exercise. On top of this, I can't really make sense of the requirement.

Therefore, could somebody break it down in "comprehensible" pieces and explain how properly these kind of exercises should be tackled?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): edit your post to show some work. First of all, what is it you don't understand in this question? Secondly, can't you see why $y^\top P^{-1}y\le1\iff\|A^{-1}y\|_2\le1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being asked to show that the two ways used to define this "ellipsoid" are equivalent. To put this another way, we have the two sets $\mathcal E_1 = \{x \mid (x - x_c)^\top P^{-1} (x - x_c) \leq 1\}$ and $\mathcal E_2 = \{x_c + Au \mid \|u\|_2 \leq 1\}$, and our goal is to show that these two sets are equal, i.e. that $\mathcal E_1 = \mathcal E_2$.

In general, the most basic way to show that two sets $\mathcal E_1, \mathcal E_2$ are equivalent is to show that $\mathcal E_1 \subseteq \mathcal E_2$ and that $\mathcal E_2 \subseteq \mathcal E_1$. That is, show that for every element $x \in \mathcal E_1$ it also holds that $x \in \mathcal E_2$ and vice versa.

This is the strategy that I would suggest for this problem. So, there are two halves to the problem. First show that if $x$ satisfies the definition of $\mathcal E_1$ (i.e. $(x - x_c)^\top P^{-1}(x-x_c) \leq 1$), then there exists a vector $u$ such that $\|u\| \leq 1$ and $x = x_c + Au$. Second, show that if $x$ satisfies the definition of $\mathcal E_2$ (i.e. $x = x_c + Au$ for some vector $u$ with $\|u\| \leq 1$), then it follows that $(x - x_c)^\top P^{-1}(x - x_c) \leq 1$.

Of these two tasks, the second (showing that $\mathcal E_2 \subseteq \mathcal E_1$) is easier and gives you a hint as to how the other should go, so I actually recommend that you do this first.

Comment: Protect the keen eye you got at very cost. Thank you sir. I'll put your suggestion in practice and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: For such a no-effort question (which shouldn't be encouraged), better hint in comment, for the OP to include some attempt in his post.

Comment: @Anne I am conflicted about the community’s consensus when it comes to “low-effort” questions, especially when the nature of the question is simply trying to understand the exercise. It’s hard to avoid “no clue” questions in a meaningful way when you really have no clue, and my answer addresses what’s being asked without doing “all the work” for the asker.

Comment: @AnneBauval not pretty sure what is that "a well-fined and thoughtful question" that might have been welcomed by your imaginary network of regulations. I merely wanted to understand how this kind of question should be approached, nothing more. 
Apart from that, there's of course an effort I put in attempting to work out this question few days ago when I lay down on a piece of paper a ridiculous solution not worth to be seen or reviewed by somebody.
That's why I essentially considered my way of approaching the exercise utterly wrong.

Comment: Cristi: no "imagination" from my side. Only still trying to learn the rules of this site. And you could/should have taken benefit from my comment above to improve your post. @BenGrossmann Thank you for your time (I also am often hesitating), though your "without doing “all the work”" is honestly arguable.

Comment: @CristiGheorghiu See [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/81360) regarding the site’s expectations for questions. The regulations are not “imaginary”; askers of “bad” questions (that don’t adhere to the guidelines I linked) and those who answer them are sometimes suspended.

Comment: And apart from that, at the very first instance you should have asked yourself "for who this question should matter most".
I asked for the recommended method somebody would equip when dealing with this, not for the answer itself. Hard to discern in between, indeed.

Comment: @Ben Grossman thank you for bringing into the limelight the exact source from where I could get a solid perspective about what a refined and "thoughtful" mark question looks  like in here, even though I walked through the documentation twice and I see no committed infringement

AnneBauval make it crystal clear and without hesitation I will adjust the question as such. What particular bit/grain within my post above indicates that the writer put no effort in penciling the question?

Comment: @Cristi The issue with the question isn't anything you put down, rather it's what you did **not** include. To quote the page I linked, *"Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true (you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem), it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts."*

Comment: @Cristi Personally, I disagree with this standard, but some ideas for what to add to the question in order to prove your effort are [listed here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933) (link is to the relevant spot of the page I linked above)